# How to compute the Weyl Character Formula

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, characters

I am asked to find the character of the standard representation of $SO(2n+1)$ when restricted to the standard maximal torus using the Weyl character formula. I know, from the representation, that this will be simply $\sum_{k=1}^n 2\cos(\theta_k) +1$, but I have no idea how to begin to use the formula, which I am pulling from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_character_formula#Compact_Lie_groups) wiki.

If I could get an explanation for how to compute it for a smaller case like $SO(5)$ so I could get an idea, that would be really helpful. I have already computed the highest weight, the half-sum of positive roots and the Weyl group. Actually computing the exponentials is confusing me.

Comment: Those aren’t exponentials (in the analytic sense) in the formula, they’re just a funny way of writing elements of a group algebra. They work more like polynomials than exponentials. For example if you’re labelling elements of the torus by $x, y$ and elements of a character like $x^3 y^5 + ...$ then the corresponding translation would be $x^3 y^5 = e^{(3,5)}$.